# How do I perform some actions in my Java program whenever a particular network interface comes up?

Tags: java, sockets

I wanted to perform some actions in my Java program whenever a particular interface comes up (network interface ppp0 e.g.). However I figured out it was way too clumsy to keep polling the interface to verify its status.

After finding out `if-up.local` file in Linux, now I can run a bash script whenever the interface comes up. Works fine, however considering my running Java program, how can I make this script interact with my Java code?

I am considering the following options:

1. Write a listening socket and from this script send message to this Java socket.
2. Invoke a C program, and through JNI run my java code.

I am looking for intuitive and less resource intensive approach.

Answer (score 3):

Probably the simplest way is your first option. Just open a **TCP socket** and make a request to it from the if-up.local script you found. Using wget/curl for example.

A more complex alternative is to somehow use a **[netlink](http://linux.die.net/man/7/netlink)** socket from java. I think that **NETLINK_ROUTE** will give you updates on interface creation events, see the first example in that link.

For this second option, either write some JNI or try to find a java library for using unix sockets. In a quick search I've found [this one](https://github.com/mcfunley/juds), although I've never used it, so I don't know if it would work for your needs.

A third idea, similar to the first one, instead of a socket, use a **FIFO pipe** (*mkfifo* command), you could read it from java as a regular file, and write to it from the bash script with simply a *echo > fifo_file*.